# Android Appium TestNG scripts not able to auto grant permission when running in Amazon device farm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testng, appium

I have an Appium TestNG script which is working perfectly on real devices, which when I run on Amazon device farm is throwing the below error.

> testcase_android failed: An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting
>   App. Original error: App never started (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 49.46
>   seconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:
>   '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15
>   10:43:46' System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

The issue is that the  capability "autoGrantpermission" to allow auto approval of permission while installing an android app is not working when I run the tests on Amazon Device farm. I understand that AWS does not take any of the capabilities into consideration. Is there any other alternative way to successfully run the tests in AWS?

Any clue or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: If the solution proposed was helpful please mark the answer as accepted solution so that others can benefit from it :)

Comment: I am curious if my recommendations solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

If you are running tests on Device Farm and chose Appium 1.6.3 most desired capabilities are honored. The few that are overridden are platformName, deviceName, udid, webdriveragent url and app path.

With the exception of these your desired capabilities should be honored including "autoGrantPermissions". See [appium/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md) for all capabilites.

Make sure that when you run this in your local setup you can run it without manually granting permissions at any point in a fresh setup. This way the same can be reproduced on Device Farm.

Hope that helps.